# Difference between BasicHttpBinding and NetHttpBinding in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, basichttpbinding

What are the differences between using **BasicHttpBinding** and **NetHttpBinding** in **WCF**? I can't seem to find any references..

Comment: this is the [official reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674273%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for nethttpbinding

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this comparison chart showing the difference between all the various binding options. I think you'll find your answer in there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx

In a nutshell, though, BasicHttpBinding is platform agnostic while NetHttpBinding is .NET only, from what I've read. So if there's a potential to roll out your web service for Android or iOS devices, I'd stick with BasicHttpBinding.